# SQL Report site gives error 404 for HTTPS brows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have SQL Server Reporting Services running on a SQL Server 2008 Standard on Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I can browse all my reports with HTTP but when I try to browse with HTTPS it gives following error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /reports/Pages/Folder.aspx

[image]

I have bound the SSL certificate and I can successfully view the `https://localhost` default page.

What can be the cause for this error?. Please help.

Comment: If I understand your question right the `http://localhost/reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` URL works, but `https://localhost/reports/Pages/Folder.aspx` doesn't.

Comment: @Warlock exactly. you got it.

Comment: Please check the Reporting Services Configuration.

Comment: @Warlock you are seriously a warlock my friend. I could solve that thanx to you. Yeah it was there under the new Reporting Services Configuration.